# jni getmethodid ()z method not found

Tags: java, java-native-interface, java-6

I am using an idxbio dll (identix biometrics api for QA of images) in my java code on an applet.
It works fine on jre1.4, we are moving our client machines to jre 6 and that where the applet gives error of idCreateToken method not found. This method returns a bool. The c code for some reason is not able to find it :

```
methodId=(*jniEnv)->GetMethodID(jniEnv,classIdQAImage, "isCreateToken", "()Z"); <--this line returns methodID as 0 however same code works for jre 1.4
```

I have tried different thinkgs like recompiling my dll with a new header file of my native code compiled under jdk6. But nothing seems to work, IF any one has any ideas that can be helpful.

many thanks,
fahad